# Next UI Change to Dark theme on the whole app

Tags: javascript

how can i switch from light to dark in next ui
https://nextui.org/docs/theme/palette theme

I am using the Dark theme in Visual Studio 2017 and have productivity power tools installed. In the past week, some of the similar word highlight colors have switched to white on white. It used to be white on blue. If I select the word "password" in the code it is white on

```
ThemeProvider
```

what property should i specify on the theme to change it to dark theme
on the whole app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ThemeProvider theme={{ type: 'dark' }}></ThemeProvider>
```